# Using a variable to store a function call?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-agnostic, compiler-optimization

Let's say I had a **pure** function which takes a considerable amount of time to run.
And in the main I wanted to call this function with the *same* arguments multiple times.

My ultimate question is, should I store the return value in a variable and use that or just call the function multiple times? Which way would take less computations?

Are compilers for modern languages (if any) able to tell whether a function is pure or not? If yes, are the compilers able to optimize away those multiple calls in the same block? If yes, then it makes more sense for me to just call those functions than to use placeholder variable (since I will be wasting computation doing the assignment/binding names)?

EDIT: here is an example

```
if myPureFunction(a,b) == 1:
    print(1)
elif myPureFunction(a,b) == 2:
    print(2)
elif myPureFunction(a,b) == 3:
    print(3)
else:
    print(4)
```

vs.

```
var = myPureFunction(a,b) 
if var == 1:
    print(1)
elif var == 2:
    print(2)
elif var == 3:
    print(3)
else:
    print(4)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a pure function?

Comment: Yes I want to assume that this is a pure function

Comment: Without trying to be rude, if you don't know the answer to these questions, then your worrying about a cycle here and there may be misplaced (not that it can't be optimised, just that you're likely to miss something much more important).

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of....

Comment: I might not have phrased my question properly, Ill try to fix it.

Comment: It's called [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (in particular, automatic memoization)

Comment: bennofs' answer was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Joowani bear in mind that in general auto memoization won't happen. The idiom of computing the output once, storing it and then using that stored value is so common as to be barely worth a mention. Store and use the variable and don't worry about the overhead; your compiler will have a much easier job of optimising *that* away.

Comment: I believe that this sort of optimisation is specific to the language or the compiler used - it's unlikely that answers to this question would be language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is depends from optimization of your compiler.
If the body of function 'myPureFunction()' is in same translation unit (your C-file), then some compilers can perform optimization for first example and replace 3x calls of function to only one.
But not all compilers can make this optimization and second variant will be better.
I said it, because our compiler (that, i implemented in my work) can't do it =)

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer you may be looking for is recursion.  It means to call the same function multiple times, however it breaks the problem down with each function call.(But I honestly don't completely understand what your actual question is)

Here is a simple recursion example from TheNewBoston that may help you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpuWkZs51aM

Comment: You may want to take another look at the question... I don't think your answer has anything to do with it.